# PHP: one PDO instance breaks transaction of other PDO instance

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, transactions

The code below works and although while having a running transaction I create another PDO object, this does not disturb my transaction:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . "localhost" . ';dbname=' . "somedb";

$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_TO_STRING
);

// first PDO object
$db = new \PDO($dsn, "someuser", "somepass", $options);

$db->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO vbclient set company = 'test'");
$stmt->execute();

// second PDO object
$dbnew = new \PDO($dsn, "someuser", "somepass", $options);
$newstmt = $dbnew->prepare('select * from vbclient where clientID = 1');
$newstmt->execute();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO vbclient set company = 'test2'");
$stmt->execute();

$db->commit();
```

But if I put the creation of the second PDO object into a seperate function it seems to kill the transaction of the first PDO object:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . "localhost" . ';dbname=' . "somedb";

$options = array(
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_TO_STRING
);

// first PDO object
$db = new \PDO($dsn, "someuser", "somepass", $options);

$db->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO vbclient set company = 'test'");
$stmt->execute();

secondPDO();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO vbclient set company = 'test2'");
$stmt->execute();

$db->commit();

function secondPDO() {

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . "localhost" . ';dbname=' . "somedb";

    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_TO_STRING
    );

    // second PDO object
    $dbnew = new \PDO($dsn, "someuser", "somepass", $options);
    $newstmt = $dbnew->prepare('select * from vbclient where clientID = 1');
    $newstmt->execute();

}
```

I get the error "There is no active transaction." I understand that this normally happens if I overwrite the PDO handle with another instance. But I don't do that and the error only occurs if the second PDO object is in another function.

Any ideas why this is?
Thanks.

Comment: Why 2 PDO objects?

Comment: Because I use third party classes that initiate their own PDO objects.